# light box not working only zooming function working

Tags: javascript, php, zooming, lightbox

```html
<td class="productinfo_imagebig" width="300">

<script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
 document.write('<a href="http://examplet.com/images/images_big/test Mat New.jpg" target="_blank" class="imagezoomer" id="image_big" rel="lightbox[group]" title="test Mat" ><img src="images/images_big/test Mat New.jpg" class="img" alt="test Mat" title=" test Mat " width="300" height="200" hspace="0" vspace="0"><br>Click to enlarge<\/a>');
 //-->
 </script>
 <a href="http://examplet.com/images/images_big/test Mat New.jpg" target="_blank" class="imagezoomer" id="image_big" rel="lightbox[group]" style="outline-style: none; text-decoration: none;">
   <img src="http://examplet.com/images/images_big/test%20Mat%20New.jpg" class="img" alt="test Mat" width="300" height="200" hspace="0" vspace="0"><br>Click to enlarge
   <div class="jqZoomPup" style="position: absolute; border-width: 1px; visibility: visible;"></div>
 </a>
 <noscript>
  <a href="http://examplet.com/images/images_big/test Mat New.jpg" target="_blank" rel="lightbox[group]" title="test Mat">
   <img src="images/products/test Mat New.jpg" class="img" alt="test Mat" title=" test Mat " width="300" height="200" hspace="0" vspace="0"></br>
     Click to enlarge
  </a>                 
 </noscript>
</td>
```

this is the code we are using zoom the product and onclick to light box pop the image here it works only for zoom it is not worked for lightbox .

can any one help me?

Comment: You didn't forgot to add the css file and images?

Comment: remove this // from //--> and use as -->

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Scan the webpage for all class names of 'thumb' that is seen.
    $('.thumb').each(function(){

        // For each class name of 'thumb' found, go to the parent item of that thumb and apply the rel attribute.
        $(this).parent().attr('rel','lightbox[myGallery]');

    });

});
```

[Demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/c2RvG/15/)
[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/u6v98/23/)